# Slim framework - how does post method work?

Tags: php, json, rest, slim

I have written a rest service application.

I send this json request to the service:

```
POST /AndroidEvent/index.php/api/events HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "data": { "name": "ApiTest", "city": "Budapest", "place" : "Budapest 1082 Népszínház utca 18.", "event_start_date" :  "2014-09-01 00:00:00", "event_end_date" : "2014-09-21 00:00:00", "decription" : "Ez egy leírás ide", "category_id" : 1, "owner_id": 2, "coord_latitude" : "47.4544", "coord_longitude" : "47.4544", "picture_path" : "http://localhost/picture_path", "is_adult" : 0, "created_on" : "2014-09-21 00:00:00", "updated_on" : "" } }
```

But on the server side in the routes.php I could not get the post data in this way:

```
$app->request->post('data') // I will get an empty array.
```

But in this way I can get the post data:

```
json_decode($app->request->getBody());
```

Is it impossible to get the post data with the `$app->request->post('data')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending a json string in a http request body using the POST http method. So in order to read it correct way is to json decode the body and then proceed. Just like you're doing it `json_decode($app->request->getBody());`

Web forms with `method="post"` encode inputs in a query string and then put that in a body. Variables sent that way can be accessed with `$app->request->post(<input_name>);`

The confusion here I think is that in `$app->request->post(<input_name>);`post actually refers to the php's $_POST superglobal which holds the decoded query stirng for you automatically. It is not the same as http method (verb) POST.

http://docs.slimframework.com/#Request-Variables